# Statistics/combinatorics question relating to Enigma rotors

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, permutations, sampling

I would be grateful of some advice on what I hope is a straightforward matter for mathematicians with a sound knowledge of statistics and probability/combinatorics.

Context

I am investigating Enigma rotors, which cause the 26 letters of the alphabet to become permuted between input and output. There are therefore 26! possible rotors. But what seems to be important in terms of the Enigma producing random permutations is that the number of permutation offsets is as large as possible. By permutation offset, I mean the difference in position between the output letter and the input letter. So for example, if A permutes to E, then the resulting difference is 5-1=4. If H permutes to D then the resulting difference is 4-8=-4=22mod26. So collectively there are 26 permutation offsets for an Enigma rotor. However, it can be shown that it is impossible for all 26 different offsets i.e. the set of integers from 0-25 inclusive to be present. So I am interested in estimating how many different rotors are possible with 25 different offsets.

Computationally, I don't think it is possible to assess all 26! permutations and keep a count of the ones that result in 25 offsets. So I have resorted to creating random permutations using the Python random.shuffle function. Over 5 billion random samples (which takes 12 hours to run on my admittedly old PC), I have measured anything between 48 and 75 of these permutations, so we are talking order of 10-15 per billion random permutations. So, these permutations are very rare, but in the context of 26!, there are also a lot of them (order 10^18)

So my question is: how many random samples would I need to test before I could be confident that my estimate of the frequency of these permutations is correct within +/-5%? What about +/-1%? I have tried dividing the sample space into smaller intervals eg of 100 million and then using the resulting data to produce a confidence interval. But I doubt that approach has any mathematical validity.

Any help or advice gratefully appreciated. I suspect this is a fairly generic problem in statistics, but I haven't been able to find an answer using Google.

Comment: So your question seems to be that if the proportion is about  $1\times 10^{-8}$, how many times would you need to sample to be $95\%$ sure of seeing a proportion between $0.95 \times  10^{-8}$ and $1.05 \times  10^{-8}$, or for more confidence and precision  how many times would you need to sample to be $99\%$ sure of seeing a proportion between $0.99 \times  10^{-8}$ and $1.01 \times  10^{-8}$?  The answer will be very large (much higher than you might want), and you might use a normal approximation to find it.  Or perhaps I have misunderstood

Comment: Thanks Henry. It's slightly different to what you have stated. There will be an exact number of these permutations with 25 offsets, but that number is too large to find by testing the entire sample space of size 26! Suppose the exact number is N. Then the exact probability of a random permutation being one of the N will be N/26! I want to find N/26! to within (say) an error of +/-5% by random sampling. So the question is, how many random samples will I need to take in order to be confident that my approximate answer is within 5% of the true answer given that the exact answer is around 10^-8.

Comment: I think this is what you want and Mike Earnest did the calculation for my first statement of being $95\%$ sure of being within $\pm5\%$ relative error, around $154$ billion.  To be $95\%$ sure of being within $\pm1\%$ relative error might need about $3.85$ trillion and to be $99\%$ sure of being within $\pm1\%$ relative error might need about $6.64$ trillion

Answer (score 2):

The 95% confidence interval for a [binomial proportion estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) is
$$
\hat p\pm 1.96\sqrt{\hat p(1-\hat p)/n}\\\approx \hat p\pm 1.96\sqrt{\hat p/n},
$$
where $\hat p$ is the sample probability that a permutation has twenty-five different offsets. I am using the approximation $1-\hat p\approx 1$.

If you want to be confident about the mean within 5% relative error, the half-width of this interval must be at most $0.05\hat p$. From $1.96\sqrt{\hat p/n}\le 0.05\hat p$, we get
$$
n\gtrsim 1537/\hat p
$$
Since your data suggests that $p\approx 10^{-8}$, this means you would require more than $1.5\times 10^{11}$ samples to get $5\%$ relative error. To get $1\%$ error, you would need to scale up that number by twenty-five.

In general, binomial confidence intervals are not feasible when estimating rare probabilities, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks Mike, this is very helpful. 5% relative error sounds doable, 10 billion samples takes me around 24 hours. 1% error, not so hopeful. One thing I am slightly worried about is how random the Python random.shuffle function is. Presumably everything is predicated on the sampling being truly random?

Comment: @TimFlack Python's `random` package uses the Mersenne twister. I am not qualified to say if this is good enough for your purposes, but based on [its wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) it seems like it should be fine.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Fair enough - I will delete the comment. Slightly curiously, the discreteness of the binomial distribution means that the precise sample size affects whether you get just above or below $95\%$:  using R code `n<-153700000000; pbinom(1.05*10^-8 * n, n, 10^-8)-pbinom(0.95*10^-8 * n, n, 10^-8)` gives $0.949$ while the smaller `n<-152095238086;` gives $0.9502$

Comment: Mike, Henry, many thanks for your help with this. I will try running 160 billion samples as a month of overnighters, 5 billion at a time and see where that gets me. If I have been incredibly lucky with my results to date, such that the frequency turns out to be significantly lower, then I can recalculate the 95% confidence interval with a more accurate value of p and increase n accordingly  i.e. this process must be iterative, as n depends on p, which at the outset is a guess based on two lots of 5 billion samples.